# Sensible Way to debug SSL connections on Android (in app)

Tags: ssl, android, proxy

I'm looking for a sensible way to test the SSL Connections my android app is doing. 
I'm running [charlesproxy](http://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/using-charles/ssl-certificates/) for debugging iOS Apps, but haven't found a way to get it working yet on android. I see the connection attempts popping up in charles, but can't select them. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, after some tinkering I came up with a good solution. However, it requires a rooted device - and only works sensibly on Android > 4.0. The real source of this is from [Dan & David](http://danamodio.com/application-security/mobile/mobile-applications-and-proxy-shenanigans/)
If you have a rooted device, follow these steps:

1. Setup the Proxy
2. Copy your proxys certificate to SD-Card of the device
3. Navigate to Settings -> Install cert from SD card
4. Install [ProxyDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.proxydroid&hl=de) (Had the best success with it)
5. Configure ProxyDroid to point to your Proxy - you should be all set!